# How to export/dump compiled MIB data from JSON into SMIv2?

Tags: python, python-3.x, asn.1, mib

I used the python library `pysmi` to compile MIB files into JSON files to easily edit the MIB objects with python.

Now I need to export or dump these Python dict structure or JSON format back into SMIv2 MIB files.
After some research I have not found anything that would do this for me.